# How to disable pinch zoom while scrolling - ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scroll, pinchzoom

I have successfully disabled zoom and pinch zoom in ios like so:

```
document.addEventListener("gesturestart", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); document.body.style.zoom = 0.99; });
document.addEventListener("gesturechange", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); document.body.style.zoom = 0.99; }); 
document.addEventListener("gestureend", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); document.body.style.zoom = 1; });
```

However I have noticed when the page is actively scrolling I am able to zoom in again
the solution above works perfectly if the page isn't scrolling but breaks/doesn't capture the event when scrolling is happening.

I also tried abit of overkill with jQuery throttle / debounce like so:

```
    $(window).scroll($.debounce(250, function() {
        console.log('Finished Scrolling');
        document.getElementById('resetViewport').setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1');

        var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
        if (viewportmeta) {

            viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1';

document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function() {
                viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1';
            }, false);

document.addEventListener('gesturestart', function() {
                viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1';
            }, false);
        }
    }));
```

But that didn't work.
any idea's anyone?